# Ajax запрос. Как сохранить данные ответа с сервера в массив и использовать его для последующего сравнения со следующим ответом?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Привет! Я не могу придумать как сохранить данные, полученные с сервера, чтобы потом использовать их для сравнения с новыми данными.
Вот мой кода отправки запроса на сервер.
Буду благодарна за ваши идеи.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var lanes = document.querySelector('select.lanes');
    var laneNumber = lanes.options[lanes.options.selectedIndex].value;

    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "http://server.com" + laneNumber);
        request.send();
        var prevThrow;

        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {
                var throws = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                prevThrow = throws.slice(0);

                var trTrows = document.querySelector('.throws');
                var trScore = document.querySelector('.score');

                for (var i = 0; i < throws.length; i++){
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
                    td.dataset.index = i;
                    var oneThrow = throws[i];
                    td.textContent = oneThrow;
                    trScore.appendChild(td);
                }

            }
        });
    }, 5000);
}, false);
```

Comment: а где вы хотите что сравнивать и с чем?

Comment: Я хочу сравнивать данные, полученные с сервера в настоящий момент с теми данными, которые мне пришли с сервера в предыдущем ответе. Они меняются. Изменения мне нужно использовать в дальнейшем.

Comment: вынесите `var prevThrow` из `setInterval` Тогда он будет сохранятся между вызовами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте переменную вне функции:

```
var GLOBAL_INFO = {};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var lanes = document.querySelector('select.lanes');
    var laneNumber = lanes.options[lanes.options.selectedIndex].value;

    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "http://server.com" + laneNumber);
        request.send();
        var prevThrow;

        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {
                var throws = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                prevThrow = throws.slice(0);

                GLOBAL_INFO.throws = throws;

                var trTrows = document.querySelector('.throws');
                var trScore = document.querySelector('.score');

                for (var i = 0; i < throws.length; i++){...}

            }
        });
    }, 5000);
}, false);

...

var myThrows = GLOBAL_INFO.throws;
if( myThrows ){
    YOU_CODE
}
```

Comment: Использовать глобальную переменную в Javascript, где замыкания - это квинтэссенция языка?

Comment: Не правильно выразился, объявить переменную вне функции. Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: А если диалог клиента и сервера будет не через ajax, а обычным способом? Где тогда хранить глобальные переменные? Без рассмотрения web storage тема не раскрыта

Comment: Задача сравнивать между вызовами. Когда будет задача в сохранение между сессиями, тогда и можно говорить о хранилищах. О разнице между `localStorage` и `sessionStorage`, и как это все работает на мобильных устройствах, если и этого коснется задача. Вы всегда можете изложить мысли в соседнем ответе, это не запрещается.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете объявить переменную для хранения предыдущего ответа в scope функции, отвечающей за отправку запроса перед setInterval.

```
(function() {
    var lastResponse = null;
    setInterval(function(){
        someRequest({
            response: function(responseText) {
                if (responseText!==lastResponse) {
                    // Do something
                }
                lastResponse = responseText;
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Так же в зависимости от того нужно ли вам точное сравнение или по пропертям, можете хранить предыдущее значение как текст JSON или как объект, но тогда придется воспользоваться функцией на подобии extend или clone, что бы избежать передачи копии объекта по ссылке.

Comment: Призывая человека использовать конструкцию `(function(){})();`, объясните что она означает, а то скоро начнут появляться вопросы, почему у меня не работает.